# Java Implementation of Q_n estimator by Rousseeuw and Croux

Tags: java, android, statistics, outliers, anomaly-detection

Is there a java implementation / has anyone an idea about how to implement the [**Q_n Estimator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale#Absolute_pairwise_differences) introduced by Rousseeuw and Croux?

I would like to use it within an Android App. In addition the app
cannot use the Internet.

For the S_n Estimator I have found an example in [MATLAB](http://biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2016/09/12/074591.full.pdf) (see acknowledgments) which I was able to translate into java.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
Why don't you try to **implement this yourself**? Seems to be straightforward: compute pairwise differences, find quartile. Also consider L-moment and PWM estimators.

Comment: well for me it does not look to be straightforward. That's why I asked this question. Did you find a description of the algorithm, which is even easy to understand for dummies?

Comment: A slightly less memory efficient version: compute x_i-x_j for all i<j. Put into an array and sort. Select the first quartile. Isn't that what the description says? First quartile of q_i-q_j? No "algorithm" for this.

Comment: Ok, I will check that! Thanks.